# Deploying an asp.net 3.5 project to IIS 6 on windows server 2003

Tags: asp.net, deployment, iis-6, asmx

This is my first time deploying a project so please bear with me.

I have a project which involves a database (sql server 2008 express) class library, webservice and a website which I want to deploy on a windows server 2003 with IIS 6. I look ed on the web and found some help how to do this for the website mostly but unfortunately not that much for the webservice, classlibrary and database.

Any suggestions where I can search/find tutorials or anyone willing to guide me through this process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply right-click the web service project and choose "Publish". Same with the web site. The class library will deploy with the code that uses it.

With this process, you'll have to deploy the database manually.

Comment: Hi again,  have been playing around and deployed everything.  there is only one issue that is bugging me.  I deployed the webservice and the website as 2 seperate published projects.  When it came to reading from the webservice from asp.net normally it worked but when a .swf file needed to read from the webservice I couldn't.  PS Server is being called correctly when not uploaded .swf calls webservice deployed and works when .swf deployed it does not work at all.

Comment: You need to debug this. Anything in the Event Log? Have you looked at the network traffic? If you were using WCF, you could just turn on tracing.

Comment: ok 10x for your help on this matter.  still now i got another problem,  i am seeing the website on my local host on the pc on which iis was uploaded.  how am i to see same website on other pcs on same network? pls help me out, this is my first time doing these things and are really getting me mixed up

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Just use the URL to the computer.